# MYSQL showing access denied for use '"@ localhost' when trying to create a new database

Tags: mysql, permissions

I just installed a new server and tried to create a new database via phpmyadmin.

When I try to create a new database I get the below error message:

To be precise MYSQL said:

> #1044 - access denied for use '"@ localhost'

Does anyone know what may be causing this error or what steps should I take to further troubleshoot?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to login again and then create db. Use the default username and password, root and empty password.

Answer (score 2):

**1. Try to login Login with any valid mysql user credentials.**

If the root user of MySQL doesn't have a password (**which is a bad pratice**) ensure to set below in config.inc.php file (for eg path: /etc/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php)

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = True;
```

**2.You can also create a new mysql user using below.**

```
CREATE USER 'new_user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'new_password';

GRANT ALL privileges ON my_db.* TO 'new_user'@'localhost'; IDENTIFIED BY 'new_password';

flush privileges;
```